# Exchange Run script when mail is sent to specific mailbox

Tags: exchange, outlook, exchange-2013

I am working on a project where we get customer feedback for performed services vie email from a form on an external hosted web server. Because there is no connection between the web server and the internal network, the email is being sent to an individual in the organization who then types the results into the system.

I am looking for a way in which this email can be sent to a mailbox and as soon as the email arrives a script (PowerShell script or .net application or whatever) is being triggered which gets the email as input, parses it and enters the information in the system automatically (how to parse the email etc. is not part of the question, just how to trigger some code and pass the email to it).

I looked for something, but all I could found was either transport rules (which do not seem to support the option to run scripts or other code, only forward or modify the email) or [how to do it for Outlook](https://www.tachytelic.net/2017/10/how-to-run-a-vba-macro-when-new-mail-is-received-in-outlook/) but this is not very reliable since it doesn't work when Outlook is closed etc.

If anyone knows something which runs directly on the exchange server, it would be highly appreciated. We are using Exchange 2013 (Version 8.0.535.0) on a VM running Windows Server 2012 Standard.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Pretty cowardly to downvote and not to mention why...

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, Exchange Server could only help you forward/redirect emails, block emails etc. with transport rules(**Conditions**, **Actions**), so are the outlook rules:

[image]

At present, running a VBA macro in the Outlook client is an available way to show the email information automatically.

Comment: This is what I mentioned in the question what I found but is not reliable enough.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the following method is helpful to you:

If your client version is windows 10, you could configure your mailbox via **[Mail](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/set-up-email-in-the-mail-app-for-windows-10-7ff79e8b-439b-4b47-8ff9-3f9a33166c60)** app. When the email deliver to your mailbox(Though the Outlook app is closed), the notification of this email will show at the buttom right corner and the Notification icon:

[image]